# Intercept GET requests and call custom single action in ASP.NET Core 3 Endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, endpoint, asp.net-core-3.1

I need to intercept GET requests in ASP.NET Core 3 and, if the request match some conditions, I need to execute an Action in a Controller (or a Page). Always the same action.

For example if the GET request match one of these:

```
\page1
\page2
\page3
\abc
\def
```

I need to execute the `Controllers\CustomController.CustomAction` and pass the request information to the controller Action.

I tried to create a `CustomEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions` following the guidance in [Microsoft Docs Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing):

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapCustom();
});
```

For the `CustomEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions` class I think I have to write a custom `EndpointDataSource` that contains all my dictionary of routes and the corresponding RequestDelegate that points to my `CustomAction`.

I followed the [FrameworkEndpointDataSource](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Routing/test/testassets/RoutingSandbox/Framework/FrameworkEndpointDataSource.cs#L17) sample but it uses the RequestDelegate writted directly on Startup.cs.

How can I create an Endpoint to add to the CustomDataSource?

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**

I've found another way: I change the request before the UseRouting():

```cs
app.UseCustomEngine();
app.UseRouting();
```

```cs
public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomEngine(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(context.Request.Path))
        {
            context.Request.Path = PathString.FromUriComponent("/CustomController/CustomAction");
            context.Request.QueryString = new QueryString($"?key=123");
        }
        await next.Invoke();
    });
    return builder;
}
```

What do you think? It's a good solution?

Comment: To intercept requests and rewrite/redirect them, as you did, achieving it in custom middleware is ok, and which is easy and flexible.